# Type conversion error in Generic

Tags: java, generics

I have just started learning about Generic.Here i'm trying to set value of global obj to the local obj's value.But i'm getting type conversion error.What is the cause for this error?

```
class GenUpperBound<T>
{
    T obj;
   public  <T extends Number> void set(T obj)
   {
      this.obj=obj;
   }

   public static void main(String...q)
   {
       GenUpperBound<Integer> w=new GenUpperBound<>();
       w.set(10);
   }
}
```

Here is the error....

```
GenupperBound.java:6: error: incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2
      this.obj=obj;
               ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Number declared in method <T#1>set(T#1)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class GenUpperBound
1 error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor-scoped type-parameter `<T extends Number>` *hides* the class-scoped type-parameter `<T>`. Those two `T`'s do not represent the same type.

This is why the compiler rejects to compile your code, because the argument in the constructor could be potentially of a different type than the type, by which the class is parameterized. For example:

```
new GenUpperBound<String>(new Integer(1));
```

The difference can be *clearly* seen if you change the constructor-scoped type-parameters' name to `U`:

```
class GenUpperBound<T> {

   T obj;

   public <U extends Number> void set(U obj) {
      this.obj=obj;
   }

   ...
}
```

Now this compiles fine, too, but `T` and `U` *clearly* represent different types.

---

You could fix this problem with:

```
class GenUpperBound<T extends Number> {

   T obj;

   public void set(T obj) {
      this.obj=obj;
   }
...
}
```

Now there isn't a second `T` type-parameter, but the constructor uses the class-scoped one. In this case statements like `new GenUpperBound<String>(new Integer(1));` will not compile, because the argument is not of the same type as the one that the instance is parameterized with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class GenUpperBound<T extends Number>
{
    T obj;
   public void set(T obj)
   {
      this.obj=obj;
   }

   public static void main(String...q)
   {
       GenUpperBound<Integer> w=new GenUpperBound<>();
       w.set(10);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your class like

```
class GenUpperBound<T extends Number>
```

because otherwise your `obj` could for example be of type String and you can't assign a Number to a String.